# Using 2 SQL Dates and want Data that falls withing this range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

HI have a table that looks as follow:

```
EquipmentID   DownStartTime             DownEndTime              CategoryID 
   142       2014-04-01 00:00:00.000  2014-05-01 07:00:00.000        2  
   146       2014-03-25 00:00:00.000  2014-04-28 07:00:00.000        2  
   153       2014-03-31 00:00:00.000  2014-05-10 07:00:00.000        2  
   141       2014-03-28 07:00:00.000  2014-04-15 15:00:00.000        2
```

Now my problem is I would like to write a report on these items that were down during a specific period, so in essence if I have a filter with a `startdate` of 1/4/2014 and a `end date` of 30/4/2014
I want to obtain all the items that was down during this period, now the catch is I can't use the following query, as this will exclude some of the above records, how do one fix this?

```
SELECT *
FROM [ABC]
Where DownStartTime BETWEEN '2014-04-01 00:00:00.000' 
                        and '2014-04-30 00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: Which record would be excluded? It looks like your query would return all 4 sample rows. Do you need to exclude rows 1 and 3 because the downtime ended after the period? they were still down in the period.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: The reason for conflicting answers below is because you haven't stated whether you only want rows that are entirely contained by that period, that entirely contain that period, or that intersect that period.

Comment: Querying timestamps (like all other continuous-range types) is covered pretty well [in this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  Essentially, forget `BETWEEN` exists, and use an exclusive end-bound (`<`).  Can we get your desired results, please?

Comment: Hey Guys, my desired result is as follow, I want to determine the amount of hours the equipment was down during my specified filter.So in essence, e.g. I want to see the downtime for april. So for equipment 153 this equipment in essence was down the whole month of april and should display this equipment for me, the same with all the items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your example data and your question, it sounds like you want a query that would return all the items in your sample data.  Meaning that as long as the item occurred sometime in your filter time, it would be returned in your result.

```
SELECT *
FROM [ABC]
Where DownStartTime < '2014-05-01 00:00:00.000' 
AND DownEndTime >= '2014-04-01 00:00:00.000'
```

<strike>Or, a little less elegantly:</strike>

```
SELECT *
FROM [ABC]
Where DownStartTime <= '2014-04-30 23:59:59.999' 
AND DownEndTime >= '2014-04-01 00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: No, **DON'T** use that second version.

Comment: as @Clockwork-Muse wrote, do not use second solution. Just to prove it try this: select 1 where cast ('2014-04-30 00:00:00.000' as datetime) <= '2014-04-30 23:59:59.999' It will return 1

Comment: Hey t-clause, its like I stated above my desired results i.e. Hey Guys, my desired result is as follow, I want to determine the amount of hours the equipment was down during my specified filter.So in essence, e.g. I want to see the downtime for april. So for equipment 153 this equipment in essence was down the whole month of april and should display this equipment for me, the same with all the items. –

Comment: @t-c, you got the date wrong in the second date time `2014-04-30 00:00 <= 2014-04-30 23:59` ;) - though I realise how it was meant to read and that you are correct

Comment: @user1546143, so what about my answer doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: This is the correct solution, I would replace >= with > since nothing actually happened that month if it ended there. The other 2 answers are wrong. @OGHaza - good observation. It was meant to be: select 1 where cast ('2014-04-30 00:00:00.000' as datetime) <= '2014-04-29 23:59:59.999' -- and it still returns 1.

Comment: Hi Brad yes, ty this resolve my issue. Thanks a lot all for the fast response you guys ROCK!

Answer (score 0):

I always do something like this:

```
DECLARE @START DATETIME;
DECALARE @END DATETIME;

SET @START = '2014-01-01';
SET @END   = '2014-02-01';

SELECT *
FROM TABLE.OF.INTEREST
WHERE DATE < @START
AND DATE   > @END
```

Comment: I am afraid you misunderstood the question